# Angular how can I get selected options (multiple)

Tags: angular

I'm literally looking for the solution to this problem for two days and I can't find a thing... Basically what I want is to get selected options from my `<select>` element:

```
<select name="selectedCars" [ngModel]="selectedCars" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [ngValue]="car">{{car.Model}}</option>
</select>
```

I thought it would bind to `selectedCars: Car[]` and I could do something like this to display selected values:

```
<h2>Selected:</h2>
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let selectedCar of selectedCars">{{selectedCar.Model}}</li>
</ul>
```

There's literally nothing in the documentation about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change `[ngModel]` to `[(ngModel)]`(two way binding) which will update `selectedCars` array as soon as you select / unselect and option in drop-down.

```
<select name="selectedCars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars" multiple>
    <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [ngValue]="car">{{car.Model}}</option>
</select>
```

---

Otherwise do add below attribute to your select element shown below, it is one as the same thing doing `[(ngModel)]`.

```
(ngModelChange)="selectedCars=$event"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `[(ngModel)]`

```
<select name="selectedCars" [(ngModel)]="selectedCars" multiple>
          <option *ngFor="let car of cars" (click)="clickedOption()" [ngValue]="car">
          {{car.name}}</option>
      </select>

clickedOption(){
    console.log(this.selectedCars)
  }
```

You can simply log the elements when ever an option is clicked as shown in the above method

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/b8JdHZXiGExDGcSR50d7?p=preview)**