# How to add the selected items to another multiple select in typescript (Angular 4 project)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two multiple select list. What is the easiest way to copy the selected items from the second list to the first list? I have to work with the final list and send it to a webapi.

I know how to do it in plane javascript, but with typescript I need a little help.

```
  student.component.html:

    <h5>Final student list</h5>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select name="multiselect1" multiple class="form-control" name="myselecttsms1">
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>

    <h5>Students</h5>
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <select name="multiselect2" multiple class="form-control" name="myselecttsms2">
            <option *ngFor="let student of students" value="{{ student.Id }}">{{ student.Name }}</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </div>

student.component.ts:

     onGetStudents() {
        this.studentService.getStudents()
          .subscribe(
          (students: any[]) => this.students = students,
          (error) => console.log(error),
        );
      }


  student.service.ts:

      getStudents() {
            const headerParameters =
                new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('access_token')

                });
            return this.http.get(environment.baseUrl + '/api/Queues',
                { headers: headerParameters })
                .map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    const data = response.json();
                    return data;
                }
                )
                .catch(
                (error: Response) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    return Observable.throw(error);
                }
                );
        }
```

Comment: You can bind the selected values on the second selector to an Array on the controller and then use them on the first selector.

Comment: So how about the solutions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666147/angular-how-can-i-get-selected-options-multiple ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you would have to install this module, for multiselect

```
npm i angular-2-dropdown-multiselect --save
```

then you add these to your import statements

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MultiselectDropdownModule } from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';
```

then in component you do this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import {IMultiSelectOption} from 'angular-2-dropdown-multiselect';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items:IMultiSelectOption[]  = [{
    id: 1, name: 'test'
  }, {
    id: 2, name: 'test2'
  }, {
    id: 3, name: 'test3'
  }]
  form: FormGroup
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      multiSelect: [[''], Validators.required],
      multiSelect2: [[''], Validators.required]
    });

  }

  saveForm() {
    this.form.controls['multiSelect'].setValue(this.form.controls['multiSelect2'].value)
  console.log(this.form); 
  }
}
```

int the html add these

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

  <ss-multiselect-dropdown formControlName="multiSelect" [options]="items" ></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
  <ss-multiselect-dropdown formControlName="multiSelect2" [options]="items" ></ss-multiselect-dropdown>
  <button (click)="saveForm()" >save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you show me an example how to work with Reactive Form in this topic? I am not familiar with it yet.

Comment: hello @PeterSmith i tweeked the code to suit your instance. I am sorry, i didnt repond earlier, i fell ill and when i recovered i was way behind work schedule. lemme know how this goes

Comment: i managed to work in a different way, but i appreciate that you answered, I accepted your answer. thanks :)

Comment: solutions from  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666147/angular-how-can-i-get-selected-options-multiple worked for me and required no multiple package installations