# How to update a multi select options from component

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to update a multi select from the component.

i use an object property as the model for the select, when selecting something the object property gets updated as you would expect.

the select code in the template:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <select multiple="" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="recipe.mainIngredients" name="mainIngredients">
        <option *ngFor="let ingredient of mainIngredients" value="{{ ingredient._id }}">{{ ingredient.title }}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

the code form the component:

```
autoSelectMainIngredients(ingredient: Ingredient) {
    // gets the ingredient id to save in the object property (which is the ngmodel)
    var mainIngredientId = this.mainIngredients.findObjectPropertyByAnotherProperty("title", ingredient.title, "_id");
    if (mainIngredientId){
        // select not updating
        this.recipe.mainIngredients.push(mainIngredientId);
    }
}
```

the multi select not updated with id when updating the model.
How else can i achieve that?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
If I update the ngmodel on ngOnInit:

```
this.recipe.mainIngredients.push("5a9e9e5a84d81edd7cb98e13");
```

where "5a9e9e5a84d81edd7cb98e13" is a valid value, it works as expected and the select shows the selection.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right value for mainIngredientId and that it has been added to mainIngredients array?

Comment: Yes, i logged it to the console.

Comment: The ngModel in the select tag should be the value of the selected option. For example, if selected option's id is 5, ngModel in select would be 5. In this case you are comparing an array (recipe.mainIngredients) with a number (ingredient._id). Either remove ngModel, or set it to a variable with the same type as ingredient._id.

Comment: That is just something wrong that I see in your code. Still doesn't explain why your options are not updated :(

Comment: Please look at this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666147/angular-how-can-i-get-selected-options-multiple/43666326#43666326)

Comment: @Aravind i want the other way around. i want to be able to control the selected options from the component

Comment: @ShimiBitton you can control selected option by using ngModel then modifying the value of your ngModel. A 2-way bind

Comment: @jeanl it works with a simple select, but when i change the ngmodel for a multiple select it's not updating the select ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer, i needed to force it to detect change by using the spread operator:

```
autoSelectMainIngredients(ingredient: Ingredient) {
    // gets the ingredient id to save in the object property (which is the ngmodel)
    var mainIngredientId = 
    this.mainIngredients.findObjectPropertyByAnotherProperty("title", ingredient.title, "_id");
    if (mainIngredientId){
        // select not updating
        this.recipe.mainIngredients.push(mainIngredientId);
        this.recipe.mainIngredients = [...this.recipe.mainIngredients];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Evn this is not working in case of a p-multiselect.

template:

```
<p-multiSelect class="pull-down" id="checkedSecMail" dropdownIcon="pi pi-caret-down" [options]="req.secEmail"
              [(ngModel)]="req.selectedSecMail" >
              </p-multiSelect>
```

ts:

```
 selectAllMailId($event,data){
      let rowData =  this.tempRecipients.filter(elem => elem.xyz == data.xyz);
      rowData[0].secEmail.map((secmails=> rowData[0].selectedSecMail.push(secmails.label)));
    }
```

The above methos is called on click of a checkbox.
And the multiselect checkboxes are getting checked, but the checked value is not not getting displayed