# How can I have a multiple select in my form without angular material

Tags: angular

I want to have a multiple select in my form without using angular material. I try this simple solution but it doesn't work correctly :

In my html :

```
 <label>Periods</label>
    <select formControlName="periods" multiple>
       <option *ngFor="let period of periodsList" [value]="period">{{period}}</option>
    </select>
```

with `<mat-select>`and `<mat-option>` it works well but I don't want to use angular material.

Any solution please ?

Comment: Refer the solution of - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43666147/angular-how-can-i-get-selected-options-multiple

Comment: I am using a reactive form ( the question you mentionned used a template form )

Comment: No need to worry. you just have to use formControlName instead of ngModel

Comment: @ManirajMurugan please take a look to my comment for your answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use formControlName

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="contry">Countries</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="contry" formControlName="country">
    <option *ngFor="let contry of countries" [value]="contry.id">{{contry.name}}</option>
  </select>
 
</div>
<div class="form-group">

  <label for="contry">Countries list</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="contry" formControlName="countryList">
    <option *ngFor="let contry of countries" [value]="contry.id">{{contry.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

ts code -

```
  myForm = new FormGroup({});
  countries = [{'id':1, 'name':'India'}, {'id':2, 'name': 'USA'}, {'id':3, 'name': 
 'UK'}];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient,private _fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit () {
    this.getUsersList();
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
      country:'',
      countryList:''
    });
  }

    save() {
     console.log(this.myForm); // 
    }
```

[image]